# Programmatically get power consumption with measurement units

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, battery

I need to measure accurately the power consumption of a process in iOS7 for a research project at the university.

I am well aware of Apple's energy diagnostic tool but a scale from 1/20 without any measure unit is nothing close to a scientific method. I am also aware of the method battery level of UIKit.

So here are my questions:

1. Is there a way to programatically get accurate statistics with possibly a measure unit?
2. Is there a iOS7 framework or some library/open source which makes this possible?

Appreciate your suggestions and help.

Answer (score 0):

The [UIDevice](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html) class reference details out a bunch of properties and notifications you can use to monitor the battery state and charge level.

You could use the battery state and charge level notifications to compute the percentage of battery consumption in your app, for example. I'm not very certain of what you intend to do with your app, but it's probably possible to harness the battery change notifications to build a data set of battery usage in your app over time.

e.g., you could use analytics to upload battery usage when a certain feature in your app is enabled / disabled. Of course, the battery usage greatly depends on other factors, but a sufficiently large data set would be able to cut out the noise.

As for the measurement units:

1. Charge level ranges from 0.0 (0%) to 1.0 (100%)
2. Battery state toggles between:

   `UIDeviceBatteryStateUnknown`
   `UIDeviceBatteryStateUnplugged`
   `UIDeviceBatteryStateCharging`
   `UIDeviceBatteryStateFull`

Comment: First of all, thanks for the reply. My problem is my professor won't accept the percentage for the measures, so basically either I switch to Android to do the testing, or I find a way on iOS. Besides, I am using the my device to do the testing so I'm not really willing to open it and attach it to a multimeter. I wouldn't like to switch to Android as I know Java but I have no experience with the Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the information you're asking for is available other than the `-[UIDevice batteryLevel` property. This is a percentage rather than units and isn't scientific in any way (I strongly suspect it's not linear).

I think the best you can do is put the iDevice on charge through a power meter and compare drain with app running vs without app running.